Configuring grub on Arch stopped my pc from booting
When trying to enable hibernate on arch, I followed all the instructions about swap file,  mkinitcpio and grub-mkconfig.
After all that, my system refused to boot, it doesn’t even get to the grub interface it just shuts down and starts again. Luckily I had the bootable drive and booted live to solve the problem.
I tried installing grub again on my efi partition but it gave the error “doesn’t look like an efi partition ”
Now this was because the partition was ntfs and according to the arch repo, grub doesn’t support ntfs so I would have to format the partition.
My question is that my efi partition has never changed and it was working as ntfs so what changed after running grub-mkconfig that made it “remember” that it can’t be on ntfs.
Here is an image of the partition that clearly shows ntfs which has been in use hitherto.


Can you please show the full /etc/fstab? If you can't copy/paste, at least take a photo that shows the entire lines? Also, please show the output of sudo blkid, and the exact command you ran to install grub.

made it “remember” that it can’t be on ntfs How about it didn't? Either the check was introduced in a recent version, or you used --force but you forgot you did?

@TomYan i used an installer for arch so i certainly didn't use "--force"
maybe it was your former statement.

"I followed all the instructions" - what instructions?

"my efi partition has never changed and it was working as ntfs" - if you meant the ESP (EFI System Partition), it is typically a FAT partition.

@Vilinkameni its clearly in the image that grub wouldnt install cause its not a FAT partition however ive been using it as ntfs since and this issue wasnt there, you saying that its typically a FAT partition has nothing to do with my question of why it stopped working.

Even Windows formats ESP as FAT, not NTFS, so it is unclear why insist on it being NTFS.  It contradicts the UEFI specification and clearly creates problems. That it "worked" is situational.

@Vilinkameni exactly, thats what i want to find out

As stated, define both: "instructions" and "working". "Working" includes surviving a reboot?

@Vilinkameni instructions are the hibernation instructions on the arch wiki page
by working i mean that ive been using arch without any issues until after following the instructions for hibernate

The exact error message you are getting on boot would be helpful. The issue is likely caused by using a filesystem type for ESP contradictory to the specification, when the instructions at Power management/Suspend and hibernate assume the standard, which is FAT with appropriate partition ID for ESP. grub-install(8) and other helper scripts generate /boot/grub/grub.cfg, so the question can be answered by comparing the previous version of that file (continued)

... as well as the files in /etc/grub.d and /etc/default/grub to the current ones. Retracing the process to set the system up in such a nonstandard way should lead to a solution. Again, this issue shows why such a setup is a bad idea. Simply put, all of the related tools assume the standard and that this setup works is circumstantial.

@Vilinkameni i get, thats probably the reason, however booting up doesnt show an error its just shutsdown and restarts from blackscreen to blackscreen nothing whatsoever.
im booting from a live usb to see if i can apply the formatting solution

After all that, my system refused to boot By "all that" / "boot", do you really mean like the "wake" attempt(s) from the first hibernation? Or did it start happening before it is ever hibernated? I feel like it could be a silly "bug" in your UEFI firmware that its NTFS driver would refuse to access any filesystem that is marked "dirty" or something like that. (If you still have the installation intact, you may see if running ntfsfix -d on the ESP helps in getting it "bootable" again.)

@TomYan yh my system never hibernated in the first place. after following the hibernate instructions on arch repo, i restarted so all the changes will take effect.
it was on that restart that my pc refused to boot. it didnt even get to grub interface it just shows a black screen, shutsdown and restarts repeatedly
